# Get File Name without path using WindowAPICodePack's commonOpenFileDialog

Tags: c#

When using the Windows API Code Pack's `CommonOpenFileDialog`, how do you retrieve the `filename` of a `file` (such as `mydoc.text`) without getting the path information?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.getfilename.aspx

```
string fileName = @"C:\mydir\myfile.ext";
string path = @"C:\mydir\";
string result;

result = Path.GetFileName(fileName);
Console.WriteLine("GetFileName('{0}') returns '{1}'", 
    fileName, result);

result = Path.GetFileName(path);
Console.WriteLine("GetFileName('{0}') returns '{1}'", 
    path, result);

// This code produces output similar to the following: 
// 
// GetFileName('C:\mydir\myfile.ext') returns 'myfile.ext' 
// GetFileName('C:\mydir\') returns ''
```

Answer (score 3):

With C#?

```
string lcMyPath = GetPathFromSomewhere();
string lcMyFilename = Path.GetFileName(lcMyPath); 

//-- C:\myfile.txt -> myfile.txt.
Console.WriteLine(lcMyFilename);
```

[Path.GetFileName (System.IO)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.getfilename.aspx)